# Removing Repeating date in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi I am trying to achieve removing repeating date from JSON array I have try mapping the array by I need partial look up the created date 2020-08-20 not full date "2020-08-20T09:28:19.055Z"How can I achieve this  here is my JSON and  code block

```
[{

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:17:42.009Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T09:17:42.009Z"
    },
    {

        "created": "2020-08-21T21:06:50.643Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-11T16:05:29.416Z"
    },
    {
        "created": "2020-08-21T12:06:14.052Z",
        "modified": "2020-07-22T13:27:45.336Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T13:07:48.751Z",
        "modified": "2020-07-22T13:28:10.370Z"
    },
    {



        "created": "2020-08-21T09:58:08.385Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T09:58:08.386Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:31:29.988Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T09:31:29.988Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T08:42:01.524Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T08:42:01.524Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:30:23.717Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-20T09:30:23.718Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:28:59.100Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-20T09:28:59.101Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:28:19.055Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-20T09:28:19.056Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T14:39:46.071Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-19T14:39:46.072Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T14:16:38.611Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-07T08:11:46.439Z"
    }
]

const data = Array.from(new Set(person.map(JSON.stringify))).map(JSON.parse);
console.log(data);
```

result should avoid repeating date if I have 21-08-2020 in created  is repeating many times but only want to give 1 time example

```
[     {"created": "2020-08-21T09:28:59.100Z",
       
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:28:19.055Z",
        
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T14:39:46.071Z",
        
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-20T14:16:38.611Z",
        
    }
]  will give [{created:2020-08-21T14:39:46.071Z},{

        "created": "2020-08-20T14:16:38.611Z",
        
    }] latest record
```

Comment: What should the result be? Are you only looking at duplicate dates for one property or is it both together? How should duplicates be removed; keep the first or last?

Comment: Also, that doesn't answer my questions (there are **three**) at all

Comment: @Arunvairavan V would review my answer

Comment: @ Abdullah Al Noor will look into it

Comment: @ Phil  only for created property need to keep the last

Comment: i did not see  25-08-2020 is repeating 5 time in your array object

Answer (score 0):

```js
let dates = [
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T09:17:42.009Z',
    modified: '2020-08-21T09:17:42.009Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T21:06:50.643Z',
    modified: '2020-08-11T16:05:29.416Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T12:06:14.052Z',
    modified: '2020-07-22T13:27:45.336Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T13:07:48.751Z',
    modified: '2020-07-22T13:28:10.370Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T09:58:08.385Z',
    modified: '2020-08-21T09:58:08.386Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T09:31:29.988Z',
    modified: '2020-08-21T09:31:29.988Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T08:42:01.524Z',
    modified: '2020-08-21T08:42:01.524Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T09:30:23.717Z',
    modified: '2020-08-20T09:30:23.718Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T09:28:59.100Z',
    modified: '2020-08-20T09:28:59.101Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T09:28:19.055Z',
    modified: '2020-08-20T09:28:19.056Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T14:39:46.071Z',
    modified: '2020-08-19T14:39:46.072Z',
  },
  {
    created: '2020-08-21T14:16:38.611Z',
    modified: '2020-08-07T08:11:46.439Z',
  },
];


let result = Object.values(dates.reduce((o, d)=> { 
  let key = d.created.substr(0, 10);
  if(!o[key] || d.created > o[key].created) {
    o[key] = d;
  }
  return o;
}, {}));


console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const things = [{

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:17:42.009Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T09:17:42.009Z"
    },
    {

        "created": "2020-08-05T21:06:50.643Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-11T16:05:29.416Z"
    },
    {
    


        "created": "2020-07-21T12:06:14.052Z",
        "modified": "2020-07-22T13:27:45.336Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-04-17T13:07:48.751Z",
        "modified": "2020-07-22T13:28:10.370Z"
    },
    {



        "created": "2020-08-21T09:58:08.385Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T09:58:08.386Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T09:31:29.988Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T09:31:29.988Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-21T08:42:01.524Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-21T08:42:01.524Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-20T09:30:23.717Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-20T09:30:23.718Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-20T09:28:59.100Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-20T09:28:59.101Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-20T09:28:19.055Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-20T09:28:19.056Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-19T14:39:46.071Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-19T14:39:46.072Z"
    }, {

        "created": "2020-08-06T14:16:38.611Z",
        "modified": "2020-08-07T08:11:46.439Z"
    }
]


const convertArr = things.map(function(item){
  
  return {
    "created": convertDate(item.created),

  }
  
  
})

function convertDate(val){
     var dateObj = new Date(val);
var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
return year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
}

var result = convertArr.reduce((unique, o) => {
    if(!unique.some(obj => obj.created === o.created && obj.modified === o.modified)) {
      unique.push(o);
    }
    return unique;
},[]);
    console.log(result)
```

Comment: @ArunvairavanV will you review my answer again ?